# Helper functions in react - classes vs functions

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

Recently I have been wondering what convention of holding helper functions is clearer, or what are the pros and cons of each of them.

So far I've been creating simple functions, which I exported individually from a ts file from my `/src/core/utils` folder. I'm getting more and more often on projects, where a whole class of support functions is created and it's the class that is imported.

My stack is next.js (with typescript) without any additional webpack configuration and none of the dependencies have any real impact on project building.

**My question:**

- What are the advantages of a class over functions?
- Doesn't importing the whole class increase the size of the bundle?

I'm starting to think about transferring to classes, because the design of `Formatters.formatRating` to me seems to be more readable than importing the `formatRating` function, which does not know where it comes from until I check imports at the top of the file.

**Class**

```
export class Formatters {
    public static formatRating = (rating: number) = rating.toFixed(1)
}
```

**Function**

```
export formatRating = (rating: number) = rating.toFixed(1)
```

I know that there is no simple answer. Functions seem more natural when choosing React, but I keep wondering about these classes.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget your third choice: Objects with function members. That's basically what your class with public static methods is, but you don't *need* to use class syntax for them.

> What are the advantages of a class over functions?

Specifically, you'e asking about classes with only static methods. Classes where you intend to create instances and hold state have advantages over standalone functions, but those advantages wouldn't be relevant to what you're describing.

Without saying whether it's an *advantage* or not (which is opinion based), the chief *differences* I can see between using a class with static methods (or an object with function properties) and using individually-exported functions are:

- You only have to import the class/object, not each function you want to use.
- The name of the class/object can be useful for categorizing he kinds of functions it has, perhaps making the names of the functions themselves shorter (but the class/object name + function name will probably be at least as long).

> Doesn't importing the whole class increase the size of the bundle?

It depends on how good the tree-shaking in your bundler is; specifically, whether it's smart enough to omit static methods that are never used. If it's smart enough to prune static methods, then it shouldn't matter. If it's "only" smart enough to prune unused exports, then it would matter — **if** there are functions/methods that aren't used. If you're using all (or nearly all) of them, they have to be in the bundle *anyway*.